# Gazebo kinect plugin needs <interial>

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros, gazebo-ros-openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to mount a kinect camera on the end-effector of a manipulator in the URDF. But the plug-in is loaded only when the reference frame has an  tag:

```
<!-- setup empty world -->
<link name="camera_depth_frame">
<inertial>
  <mass value="0.001" />
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
  <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
           iyy="0.0001" iyz="0.0"
           izz="0.0001" />
</inertial>
</link>
<link name="camera_depth_optical_frame">
<inertial>
  <mass value="0.001" />
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
  <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
           iyy="0.0001" iyz="0.0"
           izz="0.0001" />
</inertial>
</link>
<joint name="camera_depth_optical_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-M_PI/2} 0 ${-M_PI/2}" />
  <parent link="camera_depth_frame" />
  <child link="camera_depth_optical_frame" />
</joint>
<gazebo reference="camera_depth_frame">
  <sensor type="depth" name="camera">
    <always_on>true</always_on>
    <update_rate>20.0</update_rate>
    <camera>
      <horizontal_fov>${60.0*M_PI/180.0}</horizontal_fov>
      <image>
        <format>B8G8R8</format>
        <width>640</width>
        <height>480</height>
      </image>
      <clip>
        <near>0.05</near>
        <far>8.0</far>
      </clip>
    </camera>
    <plugin name="kinect_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
      <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>10</updateRate>
      <imageTopicName>color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
      <depthImageTopicName>depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
      <pointCloudTopicName>depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
      <cameraInfoTopicName>color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
      <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
      <frameName>camera_depth_optical_frame</frameName>
      <baseline>0.1</baseline>
      <distortion_k1>0.0</distortion_k1>
      <distortion_k2>0.0</distortion_k2>
      <distortion_k3>0.0</distortion_k3>
      <distortion_t1>0.0</distortion_t1>
      <distortion_t2>0.0</distortion_t2>
      <pointCloudCutoff>0.4</pointCloudCutoff>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

If I remove the  tag, then the plugin is not loaded anymore. Why is that? None of the tutorials mention this.

Also, the plug-in is loaded only when the parent of the `camera_depth_frame` is fixed. As in, if it is mounted on an end-effector frame, then the plugin is not loaded. What is happening here?

I am using ROS-kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283961/gazebo-kinect-plugin-needs-%3Cinterial%3E/) by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2018-02-28**:
Is it possible that the problem arises since my manipulator does not have transmissions defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo is a physic engine so you have to define the physical properties in your urdf or else Gazebo wouldn't know how to interract with your model and the world.

If the parent of `camera_depth_frame` is mounted on an end-effector frame it still has to be fixed on it or else you could be able to move your camera while the effector is moving which makes no sense.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2018-02-28**:
@Delb thanks for your answer. Yes the camera frame is fixed to the end-effector. But I guess since the URDF does not define the transmissions, the plugin is not loaded. I don't know why though.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-02-28**:
I wouldn't be surprised if elements of the tree are trimmed when a parent link cannot be simulated. It's mentioned in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Adding%20Physical%20and%20Collision%20Properties%20to%20a%20URDF%20Model) that a `inertial` elements are required for simulation:

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2018-03-01**:
That's strange because when I view the TF tree in rviz, I could see all the frames correctly. But as you said, I could not visualize the links beyond base in Gazebo. Why this discrepancy?
Thanks for the link regarding inertial!

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-02**:
How can you view it in rviz ? You should use rqt_tf_tree or tf view_frames.
What are the links you can't visualize ?
Even if the tf tree is correct the Gazebo simulation takes more parameters so your configuration might be correct for rviz and not for Gazebo you should check it again

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2018-03-05**:
@tfoote 's comment is correct. Gazebo doesn't simulate links without inertia. The links will still show up in TF and RViz, but that has nothing to do with it. If you look at the left side of the Gazebo GUI, you'll see that only links with inertia show up.